# Correct coloured wires for a switch live extractor fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, ceiling-fan

I’m replacing an extractor fan in my bathroom, like for like

Both old and new extractor fan are timer fans. I was expecting the terminals on the old fan to be labelled, but sadly they weren’t.

I think the colours on the wiring are pretty standard (UK) but because I’m not an electrician I’m not sure. It’s on the same switch as the light if that’s useful information

This is a photo of the new extractor fan

[image]

Which colours map to live, switch live, neutral on the new fan?

I think it’s
Red - live
Yellow - switch live
Blue - neutral

But it would be a bit of an educated guess

Comment: what did the instructions state?

Comment: And where do you live?

Comment: I can’t see any mention of wire colours in the instructions. I live in the uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t quote me on this because I’m not an electrician.
But I think in the uk it’s

- Live - Red / Brown
- Switch live - yellow / black
- Neutral - blue / grey

Taken from here
[image]

https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/387450374175951033/